# How to remove this long key from git

Tags: git, github

How can I remove `AAAAC3Nz-REDACTED-IF5kJOshC`
from (...)

```sh
pierre@pierre-Latitude-E6440:~/Documents/repos/youtube_video_player$ git remote -v
origin  https://AAAAC3Nz@github.com/Piercel2022/youtube_video_player (fetch)
origin  https://AAAAC3Nz@github.com/Piercel2022/youtube_video_player (push)
```

I don't know how I can completely remove it from my git.

Comment: That's probably a personal access token that you should now revoke!

Comment: Is there any git commands I can use to remove the long key? How to revoke it then! I am using git since 2 weeks now

Comment: See my extended answer belowm let me know it you get stuck

Comment: Somebody was kind enough to edit your question to redact the access token, but it's still visible in the edit history. (You probably can't see it, but users with enough reputation can.) Regardless of whether it's visible in a git repo, you need to revoke it.

Answer (score 3):

### That key is an access token that grants you access to the repo. You should never share it in a public space like this. Treat it like a password.

The url in the basic auth format:

```
https://username:password@github.com/
```

While this is usually one if the easiest ways to get setup, you've just found how insecure it is.

To get rid of it, you can run

```
git remote origin set-url https://github.com/Piercel2022/youtube_video_player
```

### You need to revoke the token as quickly as you can.

The token can probably be found in one of the token sections in GitHub if it's associated with your own user account.

- https://github.com/settings/developers

To securely store access tokens you can install the [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager).

It can store the credentials in a secure location for your OS. The Windows Credential store in Windows, the Keychain in macos and whatever you've setup in Linux.

On [Windows Subsystem for Linux you can also use the Windows Credential store](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/blob/main/docs/wsl.md).